# Lost internet in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, network-manager

Initially my network was not working I plugged out and in the Ethernet cable still no use , when I run `sudo service network-manager restart`, I get the output:

```
Job for NetworkManager.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status NetworkManager.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I even changed the `networkmanager.conf` file in that I changed if up down managed =true`.
I cannot see the network symbol on top right corner near the battery symbol.

By using `sudo lshw`, i can see my ethernet id card

The following output is i got after using the command `dmesg | grep enp`

```
supertramp@supertramp-SVE15117FGB:$ dmesg | grep enp | grep color auto
[     1.471648] r8169 0000:0e:00.0 enp14s0: renamed from eth0
[    27.964275] r8169 0000:0e:00.0 enp14s0: Link is Down
[   487.362883] r8169 0000:0e:00.0 enp14s0: Link is Down
[   488.939284] r8169 0000:0e:00.0 enp14s0: Link is Up 100Mbps/Full flow control rx/tx
[   488.939316] IPV6: ADDRCONF (NETDEV_CHANGE): enp14s0: link becomes ready  [   941.065941] r8169 0000:0e:00.0 enp14s0: Link is Down 
[  1802.806925] r8169 0000:0e:00.0 enp14s0: Link is Down
[  1804.844032] r8169 0000:0e:00.0 enp14s0: Link is Down
[  2258.204303] r8169 0000:0e:00.0 enp14s0: Link is Down
[  2260.717432] r8169 0000:0e:00.0 enp14s0: Link is Down
[  2275.886682] r8169 0000:0e:00.0 enp14s0: Link is Down
[  4025.514987] r8169 0000:0e:00.0 enp14s0: Link is Down
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98363/discussion-on-question-by-essie-biagioni-lost-internet-in-ubuntu).  Please continue discussing this issue *there*

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Do you get similar results if you boot from live media? thank you for helping us help you!